# Detect if a macro argument is only one symbol

Tags: macros, conditionals, parenthesis

I define a bunch of functions (or operators, if you like) using a little helper `\parens`, which adds parens on demand:

```
\newcommand{\parens}[1]{
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{(#1)}
}

\newcommand{\fv}[1]{\text{fv}\parens{#1}}
```

This way, I can write `\fv{e}` for “fv(e)”, but also write `\fv{} \colon Expr \to Var` to obtain “fv : Expr → Var”.

On paper, I would usually omit the parentheses if the argument is a single symbol, i.e. `fv e`, but still `fv (e₁ e₂)`.

How would I beef up my `\parens` macro to avoid adding the parentheses if the argument evaluates to a single symbol?

It does not have to be perfect and may err on the side of adding unnecessary parentheses.

Here is a MWE to play around with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\parens}[1]{
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{(#1)}
}
\newcommand{\fv}[1]{\text{fv}\parens{#1}}

\begin{document}
Has no parentheses: $\fv{}$.

Should have no parentheses: $\fv{e}$, $\fv{\alpha}$.

Should have parentheses: $\fv{e_1 + e_2}$, $\fv{e_1+e_2}$, $\fv{e_1, e_2, \ldots}$.

These also could have no parentheses: $\fv{e_1}$
(but that is probably too much to ask)

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Package `xstring` can check for white space

Comment: How about defining a starred version of `\fv` which omits the parentheses either way?

Comment: I’d like to make that choice automatic, so that the style is consistent across a large document, and that I can easily switch between them.

Comment: @clemens: Would `seq_split` from `expl3` help here?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer If we can assume that different “symbols” *always* are separated by comma one could set the sequence splitted at commas and then checks if the seq only contains of one item. (Alternatively you could check if the tl contains a comma. If not: less than 2 symbols...).

Comment: @clemens: Well, I thought that a csv list would be easier... but that's not what the O.P. has ...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer yes, I see. Maybe: check if tl contains a `,` or a `+` (or a `-`) and if not: less than 2 symbols?

Comment: @clemens: You're the expert in `expl3`, so I leave it to you :-P

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Could use a combination of `\tl_if_head_is_N_type_p:n` and `\tl_if_head_is_N_type_p:n` and `\tl_if_single_p:n`.

Comment: Just to clarify: what is the advantage in using this approach? IMOP it is the same as `\fv(e)` or `\fv\colon A\to B`. You have to type the braces, so why not type the parenthesis?

Comment: @Sigur: I agree with that and I would back clemens' statement about the `starred` version. It sounds clearer

Comment: @Sigur: First, the braces in LaTeX are optional (I often write `\fv e` or \fv\alpha)`. But more importantly: I want to separate meaning (this is the argument) from presentation (i.e. where parenthesis are to be used and where not), and want to control the latter centrally. This is very similar to syntax highlighting with listing: You want to leave it to the system, and you want to control it centrally.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner, I see. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it with regular expression, after checking the argument is blank: if the argument matches just a token or a token followed by a `_` and a subscript, then use no parentheses.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}

\DeclareMathOperator{\fvop}{fv}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\fv}{m}
 {
  \fvop
  \tl_if_blank:nF { #1 }
   {
    \regex_match:nnTF { \A . ( \_. | \_\{.*?\} )? \Z } { #1 }
     {
      #1
     }
     {
      (#1)
     }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Has no parentheses: $\fv{}$.

Has no parentheses: $\fv{e_1}$.

Should have no parentheses: $\fv{e}$, $\fv{\alpha}$, $\fv{\alpha_{12}}$.

Should have parentheses: $\fv{e+f}$, $\fv{\alpha+\beta}$.

Should have parentheses: $\fv{e+f}$, $\fv{\alpha+\beta}$.

Should have parentheses: $\fv{e_1 + e_2}$, $\fv{e_1+e_2}$, $\fv{e_1, e_2, \ldots}$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

An extended version where `\fv*{...}` forces automatically extendable parentheses, while `\fv[\big]{...}` uses a bigger version if the argument is not a single variable (you can also use `\Big`, `\bigg` or `\Bigg`) can be obtained with standard `mathtools` methods.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}

\DeclareMathOperator{\fvop}{fv}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\paren}{(}{)}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\fv}{som}
 {
  \fvop
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \paren*{#3}
   }
   {
    \tl_if_blank:nF { #3 }
     {
      \regex_match:nnTF { \A . ( \_. | \_\{.*?\} )? \Z } { #3 }
       {
        #3
       }
     }
     {
      \IfNoValueTF{#2}{\paren{#3}}{\paren[#2]{#3}}
     }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Has no parentheses: $\fv{}$.

Has no parentheses: $\fv{e_1}$.

Should have no parentheses: $\fv{e}$, $\fv{\alpha}$, $\fv{\alpha_{12}}$.

Should have parentheses: $\fv{e+f}$, $\fv{\alpha+\beta}$.

Should have parentheses: $\fv{e+f}$, $\fv{\alpha+\beta}$.

Should have parentheses: $\fv{e_1 + e_2}$, $\fv{e_1+e_2}$, $\fv{e_1, e_2, \ldots}$.

Should have parentheses: $\fv*{\frac{e}{2}}$; compare with $\fv{\frac{e}{2}}$.
\[
\fv*{\frac{e}{2}}\quad\fv[\big]{\frac{e}{2}}\quad \fv*{e}\quad \fv[\big]{e}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Fancy! It does’t feel right to apply a regex to the Code of the argument, when morally the condition applies to the result of the argument, but from a practical point of view it is great.

Comment: @Just_A_Man Yes, the `l3regex` package no longer exists.

Answer (score 5):

The concept of “single symbol” is somewhat vague: I can suggest an exact test as to whether the argument is, or is not, a single *token*.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*\IsOnlyOneToken[1]{%
  TT\fi
  \@IsOnlyOneToken#1\@@@
}
\@ifdefinable\@IsOnlyOneToken{\def\@IsOnlyOneToken#1#2\@@@{%
  \ifx\@empty#2\@empty
}}

\makeatother

\newcommand*{\clientCommand}[1]{%
  \mathrm{fv}%
  \if\IsOnlyOneToken{#1}%
    \,#1%
  \else
    \left(#1\right)%
  \fi
}



\begin{document}

Single token:
$\clientCommand{x}$,
$\clientCommand{\alpha}$.

Multiple tokens:
$\clientCommand{x+1}$,
$\clientCommand{x_{1}}$.

But an override is available:
$\clientCommand{{x_{1}}}$.

\end{document}
```

Here is the output (it is not much important, however: you need to try yourself…):

[image: Output of the original code]

As you see, the test treats the argument as a single token if you enclose it with an additional pair of braces.  I regard this as a feature, not as a bug.

**EDIT**

The above code will break down if `\IsOnlyOneToken` is invoked with an empty argument, that is, an argument containing *zero* tokens.  Here is a fix:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*\IsExactlyOneToken[1]{%
  TT\fi
  \ifx\@empty#1\@empty
    \expandafter\@EmptyCase
  \else
    \expandafter\@IsOnlyOneToken
  \fi
  #1\@@@
}
\@ifdefinable\@IsOnlyOneToken{\def\@IsOnlyOneToken#1#2\@@@{%
  \ifx\@empty#2\@empty
}}
\@ifdefinable\@EmptyCase{\def\@EmptyCase#1\@@@{% #1 for robustness
  \iffalse % since 0 != 1
}}

\makeatother

\newcommand*{\clientCommand}[1]{%
  \mathrm{fv}%
  \if\IsExactlyOneToken{#1}%
    \,#1%
  \else
    \nonscript\!\left(#1\right)%
  \fi
}



\begin{document}

Single token:
$\clientCommand{x}$,
$\clientCommand{\alpha}$.

Multiple tokens:
$\clientCommand{x+1}$,
$\clientCommand{x_{1}}$.

But an override is available:
$\clientCommand{{x_{1}}}$.

The bug has been corrected:
$\clientCommand{}$\ldots

\makeatletter
\ldots also for ``pathological'' cases:
$\clientCommand\@empty$, $\clientCommand{\@empty}$.
Override: $\clientCommand{{\@empty}}$.
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Output of the amended code]

Comment: That might also be quite a viable solution, if the logic is kept in mind while using the such defined command. thanks!

Comment: @egreg: Admittedly, this solution fails if the argument is empty… :-)

Comment: BTW, is this implementation of a custom argument to `\if` idiomatic? I see it the first time now, and it looks very hackish, if not downright evil. :-)

Comment: @JoachimBreitner: Yes, it is.  It is not exactly an argument to `\if`, however, but a consequence of the general rule that tokens after `\if` are expanded.  It permits you to have an explicit `\if` to go with `\else` and `\fi`, for the case in which text is being skipped over.

Comment: I’m using this for now and see how well it goes.

Comment: Been using it for a while and it looks good, thanks @GustavoMezzetti!

Answer (score 2):

The `\IfSubStr` macro from `xstring` can look for white space characters (well, blanks) between a string. However, this is not failsafe.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\parens}[1]{
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{(#1)}
}

\newcommand{\myarg}{e_{1} e_{2}}

\newcommand{\myotherarg}{e_{1} }


\newcommand{\fv}[1]{\text{fv}%
\IfSubStr{#1}{ }{%
\parens{#1}
}{\,#1}
}

\begin{document}
$\fv{v}$

$\fv{e_{1} e_{2}}$ 

$\fv{\myarg}$
$\fv{\myotherarg}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting idea to simply look for whitespace. It would not work in the case of `\fv{e_1+e_2}`, but I could probably avoid not putting a space in complex arguments.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner: Yes, that's true, and that's why I am looking for a better way

Comment: Also, I get  `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].` if the argument is `\textlambda` with `\usepackage[safe]{tipa}` enabled.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner: Well, is `tipa` in your MWE? ;-)

Comment: No, of course not :-). Looks like `xstring` has more problems with my stuff, including breaking on arguments containing `\phantom`.

Answer (score 1):

With xstring package you can retrieve the length of a string:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand\fv[1]{%
  fv~%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{%
    \StrLen{#1}[\mylen]%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\mylen}{1}}{#1}{(#1)}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\fv{e}\par
\fv{e1 e2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The length of the string does not say if it's just one symbol or a bunch of them

Comment: Would that work with `\fv{\alpha}`?

Comment: I'm not sure about the interns of xstring, but it should work with any characters, \alpha works too. \fv{e1} won't work and needs more conditionals